# Set predefined text to a file when writing to it in Java

Tags: java, file

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to write details to a file but i want to have predefined text in the file such as:
Name:
Age:
City:
Sport:

I wasn't too sure on how to do this. I'm trying to use  a switch statement and depending on the position of the array it will write the predefined text first then fill it with the relevant information. I wanted to put the switch statement in another method to reduce the lines of code in the method, but i wasn't too sure how to return i whilst inside the for loop

```html
 
  private String setPredefinedFileLines() { 
   int i = 0; String
   startOfFileText = null; switch (i) { 
   case 1: startOfFileText =
   "Server Name :  "; break; }
  
   return startOfFileText;
  
  }
```

```html
public void writeStringToFile(String[] stringContents) throws IOException {
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWriteTo));

  try {

   for (int i = 0; i < stringContents.length; i++) {
    String startOfFileText = null;
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
     startOfFileText = "Server Name :  ";
     break;
    }
    bw.write(stringContents[i]);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }

  finally {
   if (bw != null) {
    bw.close();
   }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete working code

```
public class WriteToFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File file = new File("file.out");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student s1 = new Student("Vivek", "23", "Pune", "Cricket");
        Student s2 = new Student("Vivek", "23", "Pune", "Cricket");
        Student s3 = new Student("Vivek", "23", "Pune", "Cricket");

        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);
        students.add(s3);

        for(Student s: students){
            bw.write("Name:"+s.name+"\n");
            bw.write("Age:"+s.age+"\n");
            bw.write("City:"+s.city+"\n");
            bw.write("Sport:"+s.sport+"\n");
        }


        bw.close();
    }

}

class Student{
    String name, age, city, sport;

    public Student(String name, String age, String city, String sport){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.city = city;
        this.sport = sport;
    }
}
```

Code is quite simple but let me know if you are not able to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've already got an array with information in that i want to output with the predefined values, so i wasn't too sure why my current method wouldn't work

Comment: what is the content of the array `stringContents` if it contains name, age, city, sport of one student then you can just write `bw.write("Name:"+stringContents[0])` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.io.*;

public class SampleApp {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        // For purposes of demonstration values are hardcoded.
        String name = "Desmond";
        int age = 24;
        String city = "New York";
        String sport = "Basketball";

        String fileName = "output.txt";

        writeToFile(name, age, city, sport, fileName);
    }


    public static void writeToFile(String name, int age, String city, String sport, String fileName) throws IOException {
        File fileToWriteTo = new File(fileName);
        fileToWriteTo.createNewFile();

        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileToWriteTo)) {
            pw.println("Name: " + name);
            pw.println("Age: " + age);
            pw.println("City: " + city);
            pw.println("Sport: " + sport);
        }
   }
}
```

However, it is wiser to bundle name, age, city, and sport in another class, like this:

```
public class Info {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String city;
    public String sport;


    Info(String name, int age, String city, String sport) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.city = city;
        this.sport = sport;
    }
}
```

and do this instead.

```
import java.io.*;

public class SampleApp {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        // For purposes of demonstration values are hardcoded.
        Info info = new Info("Desmond", 24, "New York", "Basketball");

        String fileName = "output.txt";

        writeToFile(info, fileName);
    }


    public static void writeToFile(Info info, String fileName) throws IOException {
        File fileToWriteTo = new File(fileName);
        fileToWriteTo.createNewFile();

        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileToWriteTo)) {
            pw.println("Name: " + info.name);
            pw.println("Age: " + info.age);
            pw.println("City: " + info.city);
            pw.println("Sport: " + info.sport);
        }
   }
}
```